# Read a File 8 Lines at a Time Python

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to read a file in Python 8 lines at a time and use the current 8 lines as str variables

However I am unable to do this correctly and would appreciate any help

```
with open("test.txt", 'r') as infile:
    lines_gen = islice(infile, 8)
    for lines in lines_gen:
        firstname = str(lines[0])
        lastname = str(lines[1])
        email = str(lines[2])
```

...

How can I achieve this

*cheers

And ty for any help

Comment: what's the content of `test.txt`?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple implementation using itertools.islice

```
from itertools import islice
with open("test.txt") as fin:
    try:
        while True:
            data =  islice(fin, 0, 8)

            firstname = next(data)
            lastname = next(data)
            email = next(data)
            #.....
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

A better more pythonic implementation

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> records = namedtuple('record',
                  ('firstname','lastname','email' #, .....
               ))
>>> with open("test.txt") as fin:
    try:
        while True:
            data =  islice(fin, 0, 3)

            data = record(*data)
            print data.firstname, data.lastname, data.email #.......
    except (StopIteration, TypeError):
        pass
```

Comment: This will result in an infinite loop.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Can you think of a scenario which can cause this snippet to be in infinite loop?

Comment: My bad it was an indentation issue, that's why I was getting different output. +1

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I have posted a better Pythonic Solution using namedtuple

Comment: `firstname,lastname,email,....=[next(data) for _ in range(8)]` will also work fine here.

Answer (score 3):

Using the usual n things at a time pattern

```
from itertools import izip

with open("test.txt") as f:
    line_gen = izip(*[f]*8)
    for lines in line_gen:
        print lines
        firstname, lastname, email, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth = lines
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this :-

```
with open("test.txt", 'r') as infile:
    lines_gen = infile.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(lines_gen), 8):
        (firstname, lastname, email, etc1, ..) = lines_gen[i:i+8]
```

**untested**

Comment: `len()` on an iterator? `len(lines_gen)`.

Comment: still wrong, the variable `lines` will raise `NameError`. And `islice() `based solution would be better here as using `readlines()` you loaded the whole file into memory.

Comment: Ok this seemed to solve what I needed after changing lines[i:i+8] to lines_gen[i:i+8] don't know if that is accurate but seems to work ty

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
every_eight = []
lines = open('test.txt').readlines()
j = 0
for n in range(0, len(lines) +1, 8):
    every_eight.append(''.join([lines[l] for l in range(j, n)]))
    j = n
```

By the way, if you're trying to accept mass input for tons of people or something, you could try using dictionaires in a list like this:

```
info = []

every_eight = []
lines = open('test.txt').readlines()
j = 0
for n in range(0, len(lines) +1, 8):
    every_eight.append([lines[l] for l in range(j, n)])
    j = n

for setinf in every_eight:
    if len(setinf) == 8:
        info.append({
                'firstname': setinf[0],
                'lastname' : setinf[1],
                'email'    : setinf[2],
            })

for inf in info:
    print inf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("test.txt", 'r') as infile:
    it = iter(infile)
    while True:
        lines_list = []
        try:
            for i in range(8):
                lines_list.append(next(it))
        except StopIteration:
            if len(lines_list) == 0:
                break
        for eight_lines in lines_list:
            # Do something with eight_lines[0:8]
```